# Insert vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

Can I do something like this?

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;

vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>("abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"));
vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>("abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"));
vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>("abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"));
```

I already know which values I want and I'm trying to create a 3 x 4 vector like this.

**Edit:** I would also prefer a C++03 solution since my compiler doesn't support C++11.

Comment: That's a vector inception, surely you can.

Comment: For some reason, I got an error in Visual C++ Compiler 2012

Comment: Show us the error, and the entire function causing it.

Comment: `error C2665: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : none of the 10 overloads could convert all the argument types`

Comment: I pasted and compiled the code exactly as I did here.

Comment: You can't have executable statements outside a function.  Also, to directly specific the vector members, you need initialization-list syntax (`{}` not `()`) which that version might not yet support.

Comment: I have those statements covered in main statement. So what I am trying to do is in fact C++11 stuff?

Comment: @BenVoigt Nice catch. I missed the `()`.

Comment: Yes, in C++03 only aggregates could be initialized by listing members, and then only in variable declarations, not in a function argument like this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use :

```
vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>( { "abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk" } ) ) ;
                                        ~~                          ~~
```

> I already know which values

Then why not this ? (C++11)

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec 
{
{ "abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk" },
{ "abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk" },
{ "abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk" },
} ;
```

Comment: Of course, if all three rows are really supposed to be equal, there's a better way to do that.

Comment: Are both solutions C++11?

Comment: @user963241 _(un)fortunately_ yes

Answer (score 1):

For repeating vectors of strings, you can use another constructor overload taking a count and the repeated element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec 
    (
        3, { "abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk" }
    );

    for (v : vec) {
        for (s : v)
            std::cout << s << ",";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/414dd4cb1e3dbc40)

Comment: This one should use `()` for the outer vector, no?  Because you're calling a constructor that does not take `initializer_list`.

Comment: @BenVoigt no, it works (live example added) because there can be no initializer_list deduced for the *outer* vector. For the inner vector it does deduce the initializer_list.

Comment: Yeah, I used "should be" in the sense of "better style", not "needed for compilation".

Comment: @BenVoigt ah, well i'm in the braces-where-you-can camp ;-)

Comment: Usually it doesn't make much difference, but for vector it does in some cases, because vector will prefer to convert that `3` to an element type rather than calling the count-and-element version.  Here the conversion fails (because the matching `std::vector<std::string>` constructor is marked `explicit`), with other element types it might not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have vector of vectors, but you initialize them wrongly. There is no constructor that accepts 4 parameters of type T. You can however make them an initialization list since c++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({"abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"}));
    vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({"abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"}));
    vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>({"abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"}));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TemplateRex I just made the code work with minimal changes. I don't code like that. Also it is not wrong, it is "just" aesthetically appalling.

Comment: @user963241 No, it won't. List initialization (i.e. "fancy curly bracket stuff") was introduced in c++11. In c++03 only things that can be initialized using lists are scalars and [plain old data types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) so you would have to do it like Devasish shown or `push_back` everything manually. I don't think it's possible to make it pretty and efficient with out c++11 stuff, which should not really be a problem. Any semi-modern compiler should already support it.

Answer (score 0):

Another one (even for prior to C++11):

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
    std::string aa[] = {"abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk"};
    std::vector<std::string> vec1(aa, aa+sizeof(aa)/sizeof(std::string));

    vec.push_back(vec1);
    vec.push_back(vec1);
    vec.push_back(vec1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that needs you to create a copy of array before hand.